# Push Project To GitHub From Android Studio Failed

Tags: android-studio, github

I tried to push my project from android studio to GitHub but it failed.
Here is the error:

```
Can't finish GitHub sharing process
            Successfully created project 'BurgerRating' on GitHub, but initial commit failed:
            *** Please tell me who you are.
            
            Run
            
            git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
            git config --global user.name "Your Name"
            
            to set your account's default identity.
            Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
            
            unable to auto-detect email address (got 'valk@DESKTOP-59LAKG3.(none)')
```

I don't know how to directly put a project on GitHub because it says that the project is more than 100 files. If I do it step by step, I miss some files. Please help!

Comment: You seem to misunderstand some fundamental bits of how Git works. You might want to look up a Git tutorial and spend some time with it in the command line before you use IDE/editor integrations. `git add -A` is your friend for lots of files, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are showing is simply telling that you are not identified on your git. It suggested you resolve by the

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

you can just follow that instruction first and show what happens next

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following worked. Please note that I'm using Windows10 and two factors verification.

1. Get Personal access token of github by:
   Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens
2. Save the token in .gitconfig by:

   `git config --global user.name "your username"`
   `git config --global user.password "your github access token"`

Please note that this will change the global setting that is stored in:

```
C:\Users\{your windows user name}\.gitconfig
```

You might be better to save the backup of this file.

3. On Android Studio, go to `Settings` -> `Version Control` -> `Git` and set the git executable path.
4. On Android Studio, go to `Settings` -> `Version Control` -> `GitHub` and click on `+` or press on `Alt+Insert` then choose `Login with token` and paste the Github token that we generated in step 1.
5. On Android Studio, from the top menu bar, go to `VCS` -> `Import into version control` -> `Share project on Github` and share the project.
6. We see an error message that says project was created but initial commit was failed. Now go to `VCS` -> `Remotes` and delete the origin.
7. Add `origin` with the URL `https://github.com/{your github user name}/{repository name}.git` which is usually used for cloning the repository.
8. Now you can commit and push. Go to `VCS` -> `Git` -> `Push`