# Trying to upload my project in android studio to github but getting message Can't finish GitHub process. how to resolve?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

using windows 10 pro and android studio flamingo 2022.2.1 patch 1 language kotlin

[image]

I tried to google and found this answer but not sure where do I need to put these two lines where to get them see them and how in the android studio?

[Push Project To GitHub From Android Studio Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026412/push-project-to-github-from-android-studio-failed)

Comment: Not to be rude, but the error tells you how to fix it. Have you tried doing that?